# How to stop gesture detector from executing long press on a single tap when item is clicked in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gesture-recognition, long-press

**Before you mark this question as duplicate please note that I have looked at all solutions to similar questions here on Stackoverflow and they did not work.**

Below is the process in which I implemented the gesture detector. You'll see that in the private class which extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener, I have only created code for a long press, yet the code contained in onLongPress also fires on a single tap.

Class implements OnItemTouchListsner **see code below**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener
```

I create a private variable **see code below**

```
private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;
```

I assign gestureDetector in onCreateView **see code below**

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerViewOnGestureListener());
```

I implement required methods for OnItemTouchListener **see code below**

```
@Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
            return false;
        }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }
```

I create a private class for the gesture listener **see code below**

```
private class RecyclerViewOnGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                //code in here executes on single tap, but should only execute on long press
                super.onLongPress(e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying overriding `RecyclerView#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` and cancel it there.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I fixed it :) It was a good suggestion, but did not solve the problem. see my answer...

Answer (score 0):

**What caused problem**

I was using [RecyclerItemClickListener (see link to github page)](https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/timehop/stickyheadersrecyclerview/sample/RecyclerItemClickListener.java) and because of this I could not use `longpress`, as the code within longpress needed to be executed inside a fragment.

So I had my fragment implement `OnItemTouchListener` and set `recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener(this)`. I only included the code for a long press within my fragment. I had also set `recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener` to `RecyclerItemClickListener`.

**What caused problem:** setting onItemTouchListener for recyclerview twice.

**Solution:** make RecyclerItemClickListener an inner class.